# How to add the content of two tuples (or lists)?

Tags: python, tuples

I already had this problem multiple times, that I couldn't find a good solution to add the content of two tuples together.
Something that does :

```
a = (1, 2)
b = (3, 4)
c = (a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1])
```

I think I saw a syntax to do just that once, but I can't remember how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one also works:

```
>>> a = (1,2)
>>> b = (3,4)
>>> c = map(sum, zip(a,b))
>>> c
[4, 6]
```

It should work with any number of lists containing any number of numbers.

Comment: @julio.alegria Yeah I know... but I thought I'd make it as short as possible... could use instead list comprehension or `list`/`tuple` with a generator expression. (i like your about me btw :D)

Comment: I would like to know how i would subtract the two lists.

Comment: @kyle You can use any function instead of `sum`. For example: `c = map(lambda x: x[0]-x[1], zip(a,b))` will do what you want. If you need something else you can come up with any other function (or lambda).

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
map(lambda x, y: x+ y, a, b)
```

I believe this is the most efficient way. You can also import `operator.add` to avoid the lambda function. For me I rather prefer cleaner global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

**With generator comprehension:**

```
a = (1, 2)
b = (3, 4)
result = [x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

[4, 6]

Comment: this is a list comprehension. A generator comprehension is `(item for item in iterable)`